rEFInd won't boot /dev/sdb without manual edit of .../boot/refind_linux.conf
I have two disks running and I attempted to get them both bootable using 'rEFInd' with no luck. All the partitions on both disks are set up for UEFI/GPT the same way. I did:
% refind-install --root /mnt/sda/1/boot/efi

... the correct mountpoint.
and:
%  refind-install --root /mnt/sdb/1/boot/efi

... and the install to sda seemed OK, but if I disconnect sda, it refuses to boot to sdb.  I get "GRUB Reboot and Select proper Boot device". (The UEFI boot menu identifies sda as '(UEFI)' but sdb is not so identified.)
But is seems that what I had to do was to manually edit
.../boot/refind_linux.conf
Although I had specified:
% refind-install --root /mnt/sdb/1       

... the mount point of /dev/sdb1, the EFI partition
... 'refind_linux.conf' continued to refer to the UUID of /dev/sda1 -- the EFI partition of sda.
After editing it to refer to the UUID of /dev/sdb1 everything is fine.  At boot I'm offered a '(UEFI)' drive to boot to so the BIOS notices the change.
Is this a bug, or did I manage to botch something?

Please edit your question and post sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb output.
